# Listview item background color based on property (WPF / MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to display a title and a color (see the picture - replace 14474460 with the corresponding color) within a ListView[image]

The color will be picked by the colorpicker (see "OrangeRed"). So everything works, SQLite database is updated, the number changes correspondingly but I can't change the background.

my XAML

```
            <GridViewColumn Header="Color">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Color}"  Background="{Binding ColorBackground}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
```

my Color property (bound to the ColorPicker - stores the color as System.Windows.Media.Color)

```
public Color Color
{
    get { return color; }
    set
    {
        color = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Color");
    }
}
```

my background color property (bound to the textblock - guess I need a brush here, right?)

```
public Brush ColorBackground
{
    get { return colorbackground; }
    set
    {
        colorbackground = new SolidColorBrush(Color);
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ColorBackground");
    }
}
```

my LeaveType entity

```
using Dapper.Contrib.Extensions;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Calendar.Database.Entities
{
    [Dapper.Contrib.Extensions.Table("LeaveTypes")]
    public class LeaveTypeEntity : Entity, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private long color;
        public long Color
        {
            get
            {
                return color;
            }
            set
            {
                color = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Color");
            }
        }

        private string type;
        public string Type
        {
            get
            {
                return type;
            }
            set
            {
                type = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Type");
            }
        }

        private Brush colorbackground;
        [Computed]
        public Brush ColorBackground
        {
            get { return colorbackground; }
            set
            {
                colorbackground = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ColorBackground");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

My helper messagebox (right after the update method) return a HEX code for ColorBackground, so I guess that isn't the problem. 
Can anyone help?

UPDATE
ColorBackground property (ViewModel file)

```
public Brush ColorBackground { get; set; }
```

Color property (ViewModel file)

```
private Color color;
public Color Color
{
    get { return color; }
    set
    {
        color = value;
        ColorBackground = new SolidColorBrush(Color);
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Color");
    }
}
```

Comment: So you change Color. You don't change ColorBackground; you do nothing with it. How will anybody bound to ColorBackground know that it's supposed to SET ColorBackground in order to force ColorBackground to update itself, and then GET ColorBackground all over again? How could any code in the UI possibly know you expect it to do all that stuff? Here's how to do it: Make ColorBackground a normal get/set property, no clever stuff in the setter. Then have the Color property's setter set it when Color changes: `ColorBackground = new SolidColorBrush(Color);`.

Comment: What's LeaveTypeEntity for? It's got the same properties as your other class, though they're defined a little differently. Are you certain you know which of the two classes those UI properties are bound to?

Comment: I use LeaveTypeEntity for my database updates (and it's working fine - although I have to refactor my whole code when I am done. This is my first project so there might be some strange code). Did what you said, when choosing a new color I get a hex code in return (MessageBox) from ColorBackground so at least the hex code is here, but the textblock is still white

Comment: attached the two small code updates in my first post. I placed a textblock outside the listview stuff and there the background is changing properly.

Comment: So it looks like `LeaveTypeEntity` is the item in the ListView. That's the BackgroundBrush property you're binding to with TextBlock.Background in your DataTemplate, and that's the Color property you're binding TextBlock.Text to in your DataTemplate. I have no idea how or if you're setting `LeaveTypeEntity.Color` in the ListView items, but if you're doing that somehow, then your `LeaveTypeEntity.Color` property's setter needs to set `LeaveTypeEntity.BackgroundBrush` just like the corresponding properties do in your ViewModel class.

Comment: If you want any further help, post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If `LeaveTypeEntity` is the data model  for the `ListView` (?) you need to make sure that the `ColorBackground` property has a value. You posted three different versions of the `Color` and `ColorBackground` properties. I think you should clarify and improve your question.

Comment: Like Ed said, changing the LeaveTypeEntity stuff accordingly solved my problem. The main mistake I made is to name the color "Color" so I had trouble with the "struct System.Windows.Media.Color". I really have to refactor my code and use proper naming conventions along with a cleaner code. thanks Ed for your patience!

Comment: @Moritz My pleasure! Glad you got it sorted.